# Nikon D5100 not getting battery power after being dropped?

Tags: nikon, repair, equipment-damage, nikon-d5100

My Nikon D5100 hit the pavement when the strap broke.  Since then, I have no power.  A local camera shop agreed there was no battery power and suggested a new battery.  After charging the new one, I still have no power to the camera - no lights, no shutter, nada....  Any suggestions before I take it in for repairs at an incredible cost?

Comment: Nope.  The fancy technical term is "busted".  Now would be a good time to invest in a decent strap.  That last cheap one was really expensive.

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably need to get it serviced.  There are a lot of other things that could be wrong from that harsh of a drop anyway.

Also, don't go to the same camera shop you went to.  Replacing the battery made no sense at all for your scenario.  They were either incompetent at their jobs or worse, just wanted to get money from you by selling a battery you didn't need.  Dropping a camera wouldn't make a battery go bad.  It might cause a break in the connectors within the camera, but you could chuck a battery around the room all day long and it wouldn't do a thing to it unless you managed to break the case.

Your best bet is going to be to contact Nikon directly probably.  It may not even be a power related problem.  If some other hardware was damaged, it may simply fail to power up despite having power provided to it.

Comment: Considering the price of a new D5100, the OP should do well to ask for an estimate of repair costs first...

Comment: @EsaPaulasto - I would expect that Nikon would quote the cost prior to doing service.  I know that is how Canon does it and I can't imagine that Nikon would do it differently as it wouldn't make very good customer relations to not provide an estimate before doing the service, but yes, it wouldn't hurt to ask specifically for an estimate, though at the point it would cost more than a new one, they would simply send a refurbished model back in place of it anyway.

Comment: "Also, don't go to the same camera shop you went to." This should be bold. Red. And blinking.

Comment: Can't help wondering if they sold you the strap as well...

Comment: +1 for "don't go to the same camera shop". Any reputable shop should have tested it with one of their own batteries if there had been any reason to suspect that was the problem.